# Is there a way to restrict items from being submitted if it misses a deadline date?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I've created an approval workflow but I want to be able to restrict items from being submitted if it misses a deadline date?

Sorry if that doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a `Column Validation` to submit your form in case the formula is valid

**Steps:**

- Open List Settings.
- below Columns > Click on your column (Due Date) to edit it
- At `Column Validation` > add your formula as you prefer.

**Example:**

You want to submit the form, in case the due date is greater than today! , so the formula would be

```
=[Due Date] > today()
```

[image]

**{OutPut}**

When you try to set [Due Date] **less than** Today, The form will not be submitted and you will get the `User Message` that  you have set in the Column validation

[image]